# Obtaining stack trace on application crash on Android 10

Tags: android, debugging, apk, crash-reports

I have two devices - one with Android 7 (Xiaomi Redmi 4A), and another with Android 10 (Huawei P20).
I am developing an application on those devices (from `Termux`, using [BuildAPKs](https://github.com/BuildAPKs/buildAPKs) scripts).

I sometimes make errors (like null pointer dereference), and when it happens, the application crashes.

When it crashes on the Android 7 device, a popup appears, which says that "the application crashed", and it lets me "see details", which shows a stack trace with the file and the line of illegal instruction.

However, when it crashes on Android 10, the app window just disappears and it takes me to the home screen.

Is there any way to obtain the crash report on Android 10 as well?
(I once tried using an Android 8 Huawei tablet, but it also didn't display any crash reports)